# Please explain the replaceall method in the code below and how the output is not replace by $1

Tags: apex, string

```
String x = 'The !shorn! sheep !sprang!.';  
System.debug (x.replaceAll ('!(.*?)!', '$1'));
```

The output is:

> The shorn sheep sprang.

Answer (score 7):

$1 allows you to reference the first "capture group" in the match. In other words, the value from `(.+?)` is replaced, while the bits around the match are discarded. You can use capture groups to, say, reorganize data in a string. As another example, say you have a date in the form of YYYY-MM-DD, and you wanted it to be MM/DD/YYYY. You could do that with the following code:

```
myDateString.replaceAll('(\\d+)-(\\d+)-(\\d+)','$2/$3/$1');
```

You'll want to read more about capture groups in the Java [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) class, especially the comments written there; the [Apex Code Matcher](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_matcher_methods.htm) class also makes mention of this behavior.

Comment: Bah beat me to it! Much better than what I would have written up though. Thanks for the documentation. Fwiw Apex now also has `Matcher` [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_matcher_methods.htm).

Comment: Thanks, Adrian. I didn't realize they'd included the text; I've updated my answer. It seems to be copied directly from the Java version of the documentation, though.

Comment: Heh that figures. At least now it's easier to google-fu.